# Html redirection using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to link my back `Node js api` with my html pages .

for almost cases everything works well but I got confused at some point

What is the efficient way to follow in redirecting a html page because I usually use node js to do that like this  which it seems to me wrong ? I think

```
res.sendfile('event.html')
```

but I saw in different page this statement which allows to jump from page to another

```
<div class="ui-block-title">
    <h6 class="title">Events</h6>

        <a href="/events.html" class="more">Create New</a>
</div>
```

could it possible to light on how to link the href part with node js backend ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

probably you've got different routes in your node server, if you want to redirect to specific route you can just res.redirect('target') so if you're using express it would look sth like

```
const app = express()

app.get('/', (res, req, next) => {
  res.render('index')
}))

app.get('/some-route' , (res, req, next) => {
  res.redirect('/')
}))

app.listen(3000)
```

here if you go to main page the index page will be rendered, but it you go to foo.com/some-route you will be redirected to main page

thats in principle how redirection works with Node. Hope that this answers your question.

Comment: and when u rendering a html page for the post part `methode ="POST"` we must  use `<form action="" method =""> `or we can communicate in different methode  like the exemple mentioned above  `href`

Comment: if you have post then just instead of app.get use app.post rest is exactly the same. 
just remember if you want to send html you use res.send('html-file') but if you've got anything templated with ejs / pug you should use res.render('file')

Answer (score 0):

**Use Express.js a nodejs framework**

**Install & Include Express.js framework in your project**

```
express = require("express"),
app.set("view engine", "ejs");    //setting all files view as .ejs
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Now create a **.ejs** file and wrap it around html because at **backend normal html can't be rendered**

> To wrap Do <%= > around each content object where you want to display some content
>   object
>
> HomePage.ejs

```
<h1>HomePage!</h1>
```

**Now call your html file using :-**

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {   // no need to add .ejs as we had set all at ejs
res.render("HomePage");          
});

// Output:
// HomePage!
```

Comment: but I'm looking for .html not ejs so how to display data in  .html pages  something different from `<%=>`